# How can I manipulate field properties dynamically?

Tags: c#, winforms, linq, telerik

I have some tables with the field property Active. The tables are using the same RadGridView. Par example the table MyLinqTable.

How can I dynamically update the contents of the field value Active?

```
private void CheckItemChanged()
{
   ...
       bool value = (GridView.CurrentRow.DataBoundItem as MyLinqTable).Active;
       (GridView.CurrentRow.DataBoundItem as MyLinqTable).Active = !value;
       Db.SubmitChanges();
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is my solution. You had to check if the DataBoundItem has a property with the name "Active". And then you can change the value of Active.

```
   private void CheckItemChanged()
   {
       if (
            GridView.CurrentRow != null && 
            GridView.CurrentRow.DataBoundItem != null &&
            GridView.CurrentRow.DataBoundItem.GetType().GetProperty("Active") != null)
       {
           dynamic dataItem = GridView.CurrentRow.DataBoundItem;
           bool value = dataItem.Active;
           dataItem.Active = !value;

           Db.SubmitChanges();

           RefreshItems();
       }
    }
```